# How to reference an attribute that is in the base XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have two schema files one is the base and it have a restriction element and the main schema has an element which is referencing the base one the problem is it gives the following error when opening the file in Liquid studio 2020

[image: Errors from schema validation]

The base schema file ( saudiedi.xsd )

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sau="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" xmlns:cm="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="abstractPayloadType" abstract="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>abstract payload for domain teams to define</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="msgIDType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\c{1,3}\d{1,14}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="recordType">
        <xs:sequence>       
            <xs:element name="payload" type="sau:abstractPayloadType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="saudiEDIType" abstract="true" block="extension">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>boilerplate for saudiedi documents</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="record" type="sau:recordType" maxOccurs="999"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="docType" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="sau:msgIDType" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="msgType" use="optional"/>       
    </xs:complexType>


</xs:schema>
```

and the main schema file ( TRFSTS.xsd )

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:trfSts="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/trfMafSts" xmlns:cmSts="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/cmSts" xmlns:trfMafCm="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/trfMafCm" xmlns:sau="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" xmlns:cm="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/trfMafSts" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="../Common/common.xsd" namespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="../Common/saudiedi.xsd" namespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="../Common/cmSts.xsd" namespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/cmSts" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="trfMafCommon.xsd" namespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/trfMafCm" />
    <!-- Payload implementation -->

    <!-- some elements are defined here but I didn't copy them for simplicity and the have nothing to do with the problem -->

    <xsd:element name="record" type="sau:recordType" />

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="id-ref">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="sau:msgIDType" use="required"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="docType-ref">
        <xsd:attribute name="docType" fixed="MAF" use="required"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="msgType-ref">
        <xsd:attribute name="msgType" fixed="TRFSTS" use="required"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

    <!-- SaudiEdi Framework -->
    <xsd:complexType name="saudiediTrfStsType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="sau:saudiEDIType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref="trfSts:record" maxOccurs="999" />
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attributeGroup ref="trfSts:docType-ref"  />
                <xsd:attributeGroup ref="trfSts:id-ref"/>
                <xsd:attributeGroup ref="trfSts:msgType-ref"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="saudiEDI" type="trfSts:saudiediTrfStsType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I think we need more information. What have you tried, and what happened? Also, I think you asked a very similar problem a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: I've tried using **attribute** instead of **attributeGroup** but I got the same problem .. I don't actually know where does the problem come from as I have did the same thing with the **record** element and it solved the problem

Comment: Mr @kimbert any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not clear on which error you are asking about. Please try not to use screenshots - they are difficult to read, and difficult to paste into Google. You need to use your own time to make the question easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simplify the main schema file. it looks like you are trying to use the complex type defined in the saudiedi.xsd file but you are trying to wrap it in another complex type and you are defining the attributes groups local again. this is causing all sorts of errors.

If you remove all this from the main schema file

```
<xsd:element name="record" type="sau:recordType" />

<xsd:attributeGroup name="id-ref">
  <xsd:attribute name="id" type="sau:msgIDType" use="required"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>

<xsd:attributeGroup name="docType-ref">
  <xsd:attribute name="docType" fixed="MAF" use="required"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>

<xsd:attributeGroup name="msgType-ref">
  <xsd:attribute name="msgType" fixed="TRFSTS" use="required"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>

<!-- SaudiEdi Framework -->
<xsd:complexType name="saudiediTrfStsType">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="sau:saudiEDIType">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="trfSts:record" maxOccurs="999" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attributeGroup ref="trfSts:docType-ref"  />
      <xsd:attributeGroup ref="trfSts:id-ref"/>
      <xsd:attributeGroup ref="trfSts:msgType-ref"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and replace

```
<xsd:element name="saudiEDI" type="trfSts:saudiediTrfStsType" />
```

with this:

```
<xsd:element name="saudiEDI" type="sau:saudiEDIType" />
```

it will give no more errors and I think that will give you what you originally intended to achief.